# Refreshing pages without calling external pages with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

is there a way of only refreshing a div without calling an external page into it. i have a div on my page which have a dynamic binding bind to it and i want it to refresh every 3 seconds. there's this code i have but that seems to load external pages.

```
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); // This part addresses an IE bug. without it, IE will only load the first number and will never refresh
    setInterval(function() {
    $('#freq_count').load('count_freq.asp');
    }, 3000); // the "3000" here refers to the time to refresh the div. it is in milliseconds.
    });

    // ]]></script>
```

i believe there's a way out where i can only refresh a div without calling in a page.

Comment: Can you explain in more details what you want? Or can you attach screenshot of your problem?

Comment: i want to only refresh a div without calling in an external page for example:  $('#freq_count').load('NO PAGE LOAD');

Comment: So, you want to load only div from the whole markup that comes from `count_freq.asp`, right?

Comment: what i mean is there is a particular value i called from the database into the div named #freq_count and i want to only refresh #freq_count every 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your need correctly, jQuery's `load` already has this out of the box:

```
$('#freq_count').load('count_freq.asp #freq_count');
```

This will query the whole page (of course, what else could request to `count_freq.asp` query), but load only filtered part into the div.

Comment: i only used this and it work: $('#freq_count').load('#freq_count'); but destorys my page layout but i'll work on it